# Why "Remove Unused Resources" doesn't find anything in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring

As you might know, `Remove Unused Resources`has added recently to Android Studio, [Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio20preview5available).

I run this function by right click on the name of project then `Refactor/Remove Unused Resources`. It shows a dialog and nothing happens when I click `Refactor` or `Preview` buttons. I believe there must be a lot of problems since this is a very big project but I don't see result. Are you able to see any result?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I just found what is the problem.

The problem was, as I mentioned I was right clicking on project name and did refactoring from there. So this way doesn't work (Android Studio guys must disable this functionality to not staffing people around)

So, By running `Analyze/inspect code` I could see a list of unused resources. I doubled clicked on an String item then `String.xml` opened and by doing `refactoring/remove unused resources...` all resources removed :+1

So it was the trick. I could see all changed files on git. Hope it helps you guys.