# Removing not used resources in Android

Tags: android, python, android-resources

Android has recently added `Unused resource remover` functionality into Android Studio but for some reasons it doesn't work (I asked a question regard that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34866226/513413)).

I found [android-resource-remover](https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover) in my search to find a replacement tool. I had a little bit problem in installation but I was successful to install it at the end ([thanks to CA77y](https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover/issues/40)).

I have two questions now:

1. By installation of my Python virtual environment a directory added to root of my project. Should I add it into repo (to be accessed by other developers) or I should add it into `.gitignore` (if it contains machine dependent configurations)?
2. The important thing is nothing happens when I run following command and no resource remove regardless of I run it under virtual env or not. This is screenshot of my output.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why "Remove Unused Resources" doesn't find anything in Android studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866226/why-remove-unused-resources-doesnt-find-anything-in-android-studio)

Comment: Actually I don't think this duplicate of that question since target of this question is `android-resource-remover` while that one is Android studio. My answer to that question is not answer of this question although the aim of both of them is removing unused resources.